# How to select part of data after minimum point of column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with column 'Value' , i want to get part of data after minimum value of data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16]})

Desired output:
df_out=pd.DataFrame({'value':[15,20,15,16]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if no default index - get position by `np.argmin` and add `1`, select by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[df['value'].to_numpy().argmin() + 1:]
print (df)
   value
6     15
7     20
8     15
9     16
```

Comment: I believe you can can skip the `to_numpy`.  `df.iloc[df['value'].argmin() + 1:]`

Comment: @piRSquared - It sometimes return error, if I remmeber well ;)

Comment: I think it is a Pandas version issue.  At some point they added `argmin`, took it away, and added it back ?  But, I agree, leaving it is safer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.idxmin`, with `.index.get_loc` and `.iloc`, eg:

```
df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(df['value'].idxmin()) + 1:]
```

Will give you:

```
   value
6     15
7     20
8     15
9     16
```

Optionally `.reset_index()`.

Comment: Or this *perfectly* reasonable version `df.iloc[min(range(len(df)), key=[*df.value].__getitem__) + 1:]`  BTW nice avatar (-:

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see what the problem is now.  `idxmin` returns the index value at the first minimal point.  This solution works fine if the index is the same as `pd.RangeIndex(len(df))` but it breaks down under any other circumstance.  If the index starts at ... `3` `df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16]}, range(3, 13))`.

Comment: @piRSquared thanks for pointing that out... edited to be more robust but not exactly elegant :(